# What exactly is 'Dark Matter'?

Tags: dark-matter

There are many documentaries, forums, blogs and more dedicated to [Dark Matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter). I have been frantically searching for an answer to my question however none of my sources have clarity to the matter of hand. I would really love a clear explanation to: What exactly is Dark Matter? Please help me to have a clear understanding.

Comment: Related : http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1008/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2131/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47779/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do we know Dark Matter isn't simply Neutrinos?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17227/)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because all questions are more about "why is dark matter not this and that?", while this question asks "What is dark matter?". I somehow have a feeling the OP will not find a satisfying answer in the duplicate links.

Comment: Everything we know about Dm is pretty much summed up in this song: https://jonnyberliner-sciencesongs.bandcamp.com/track/dark-matter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We don't know.

Though there are several ideas what dark matter *could* be, e.g. the humorously abbreviated [WIMPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles), all we know about dark matter is that is it *massive* (by light deflection, etc., etc.) and that it does not interact electromagnetically, and probably also not with the strong force. Other than that, there is no sufficently tested theory of dark matter to pronounce with confidence what it is. We only know what it is *not* (i.e. not EM charged, not strongly charged, and there are probably a few other constraints from observation).

Also, though highly unlikely, it could be that it is our theory of *gravity*, i.e. GR, that needs to be modified. In that case, it could be that there is no additional unknown matter, just different gravitational interactions from what we currently think.

Comment: On the modified gravity, [$f(R)$ gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F(R)_gravity) is one of the most common I see in the literature. [TeVeS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor–vector–scalar_gravity) is also popular.

Answer (score 2):

"Dark matter" is just a name invented for the gravitational effects we see around galaxies and galaxy clusters. For example, the Milky Way has a "dark matter halo" that effects the orbit of the particles around the center of the galaxy. We can plot the orbits on a **rotation curve**. See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_rotation_curve.

To agree with ACuriousMind, we know very little about this substance! The only way we know it even exists (which we are not completely sure of) is by its gravitational effects. Dark matter does not interact with light, since it does not reflect, absorb, or scatter light.

Answer (score 1):

Dark matter is introduced into cosmology because Einstein's GRT does not correctly give the rotational speeds observed in galaxies, except to suppose that additional matter otherwise not observable would correct this.

Other cosmologies such as GEM (heaviside et al), give a correct explanation of this and therefore do not need a corrective fix.

Comment: If you want to go with this answer please could you not just put forward how an alternative theory explains a *single* piece of observational evidence, but how it addresses the myriad pieces of evidence that seem to point to non-baryonic dark matter -e.g. early nucleosynthesis, cluster velocity dispersions, growth of structure, baryon acoustic oscillations...

Comment: Dark matter is used because GRT only has attractive gravity, whereas GEM has a repulsive force as well, and this explains a lot of what you're saying,  SRT is common to both theories, but in GEM, it is a consequence of space.

Comment: OK, that's of interest. However it needs to explain *all* of what I'm saying at least as well as dark matter if it is to be regarded as a better model. Your answer is still only partially correct because dark matter is introduced not *just* because it is a fix to solve the problem of galaxy rotation curves. That is misleadingly simplistic.

Comment: From what i read of it, it's non-bayonic because we can not detect it in the milky way.  But GEM gives the right rotation field for galaxies, and associates the mercury anomaly with the proper motion of the sun at 250 kms.  Likewise, the dirac clouds, the beams radiating from pulsars, the butterfly nebulus, the shape of galaxies, and the origion of the solar system from a sunspot all have a simple explanation in GEM.

Comment: "The origin of the solar system from a sunspot"... Enough said.

Comment: http://www.mrelativity.net/Papers/14/tdm23.pdf explains a giant solar flare that condensed at rates, leaving jupiter to clean up the tail.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. Historically dark matter was introduced due to inconsistencies in the observed velocity distributions of galaxy clusters, not rotation speeds within galaxies. Today, dark matter correctly pre/postdicts dozens of observations correctly, including the Cosmic Microwave Background etc. No other cosmology has been proposed that can explain all those observations simultaneously.

Comment: I think that because dark matter doesn't  scatter light it could be space itself ,  but space with a very high concentration of vacuum particles that have mass through an unusually strong interaction with the Higgs field  .

Comment: Dark matter has not been observed, for much the same reason that pixie dust hasn't.  The thing is that it is known only through an anomalie (ie nature - theory), and in general, this is a marker for the theory being incomplete or wrong.